# Silverlight datagrid performance - ScrollToPercent

Tags: performance, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I'v run into an preformance releted problem with a DataGrid in an Sliverlight 4 application that I'm currently working on.

In our application we have a DataGrid which is quite huge, up to 4000 rows.

Its obviously extreamly slow to scroll a grid this big. Lets say you grab the tracker in scrollbar at the top and drag the mouse courser to the bottom. The tracker eventually reaches the bottom but it takes a few minutes.

It seams like Silverlight wants render ALL rows that it passes.

Using the ScrollToPercent method works like a charm though, so what I would like to do is to use ScrollToPercent when you release the tracker.

You follow? Lets say I grab the tracker and then I can move it up and down the scrollbar WITHOUT the view changing, but as soon as I release the tracker it should trigger a ScrollToPercent.

Did that make sense? Is this possible, or do you have a suggestion that in another way can help me solve this problem?

Comment: You Should Use Pager For Solve This Issue

Comment: Absolutely, thats the recommended approach with this amount of data. The problem is that the customer dont want to solve it that way, insist on having all the rows loaded.

Comment: +1 for other option that you want to search.

Comment: Have you ever figured out this issue? It's rendering problem I beleive